# Plugin to get app-version from app store for cordova app?

Tags: android, ios, plugins

I need a plugin for getting app version from play store.

I want to notify user to update latest version if it is present in app store. Want to show kind of notification to user as soon as user running app.

I need that plugin for both android and ios.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need to run your own service to check the versions numbers of your app.

e.g. mywebsite.com/myappversionnumber.php?version=android

Or some such

Answer (score 0):

you can use "cordova-plugin-app-version" plugin to get version of installed app then you can call api service to check app is latest or not.